# Ansible include_tasks is not running in parallel on all hosts

Tags: ansible

I have a list of tasks clubbed into a different yaml file and I am calling this yaml from my main.yaml with an include statement.

Now the problem is, the tasks that are part of include statement are getting executed node by node instead of parallel. Other tasks that are part of my main.yaml are getting executed in parallel. This node by node execution behavior is significantly increasing execution time of my playbook.

How shall I overcome this shortcoming?

Comment: Would the keyword `serial: "100%"`, per the [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size) be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: If you need something more than that, it could be worth looking into the [`async_status` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/async_status_module.html#async-status-obtain-status-of-asynchronous-task): some use cases for this module (provisioning multiple AWS EC2 instances with parallel execution) are shown here: [1](https://blog.crisp.se/2018/01/27/maxwenzin/how-to-run-ansible-tasks-in-parallel), [2](http://toroid.org/ansible-parallel-dispatch). See also [this](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-actions-and-polling)

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your main.yaml and included tasks file looks like?

Comment: If you can (it's not in a loop), try `import_tasks` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The flow is as expected.

Ansible would run the playbook across all nodes in parallel or in a serial way depending on the configuration used.

The tasks inside the main playbook would happen sequentially as per the module defined.

To solve the problem you have to use async module. link below.

[async module ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html)

Comment: I found the issue. I observed this issue when I use include with with_items.Fixed this issue by applying with_items to all the tasks that are part of my include file.